# Rearranging a string

Tags: java

So my goal is to rearrange a string that is inputted into the program so that it outputs the same info but in a different order. The input order is `firstName` `middleName`, `lastName`, `emailAddress` and the intended output is `lastName`, `firstName` `first letter of middleName` `.`

For example the input

`John` `Jack`,`Brown`,`JJB@yahoo.com`

would output

`Brown`, `John` `J` `.`

Here's what I have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameRearranged {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a name like D2L shows them: ");
    String entireLine = keyboard.nextLine();
    String[] fml = entireLine.split(",");
    String newName = fml[0].substring(7);
    String newLine = fml[1] + "," + newName + ".";
    System.out.println(newLine);
  }

  public String substring(int endIndex) {
    return null;    
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how to separate the `firstName` and `middleName` so I can `substring()` the first letter of the `middleName` followed by a `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This meets your required output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameRearranged {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a name like D2L shows them: ");
        String entireLine = keyboard.nextLine();

        String[] fml = entireLine.split(","); //seperate the string by commas

        String[] newName = fml[0].split(" "); //seperates the first element into 
                                              //a new array by spaces to hold first and middle name

        //this will display the last name (fml[1]) then the first element in 
        //newName array and finally the first char of the second element in
        //newName array to get your desired results.
        String newLine = fml[1] + ", " + newName[0] + " "+newName[1].charAt(0)+".";

        System.out.println(newLine);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
public class NameRearranged {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a name like D2L shows them: ");
        System.out.println(rearrangeName(keyboard.nextLine()));
    }

    public static String rearrangeName(String inputName) {
        String[] fml = inputName.split(" |,"); // Separate by space and ,
        return fml[2] + ", " + fml[0] + " " + fml[1].charAt(0) + ".";
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps split on `",\\s*|\\s+"`, which (for the benefit of @moo) means split on either/or (`|`) a comma followed by zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) or no comma but one or more spaces (`\\s+`). This gives a little more flexibility for user input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delimit the string for spaces as well. And don't forget the alternate "|" character. Try the following.

```
String[] fml = entireLine.split(" |, ");
```

Comment: The only problem is that every space represents a new element. Such as: John Joe, Doe, johndoe@gmail.com would = 6 elements instead of the desired 4.